# Text classification: training based on long documents and applying it for short sentences

Tags: python, text-classification, supervised-learning

I'm a beginner in NLP and have a general question (maybe too general). I have two datasets. The first is agricultural patents documents with a given classification into classes. The second is a list of words/short sentences (agricultural tasks such as "Apply manure" or "Disk"). My goal is to classify each task into one of the patent classes.

At this stage, I don't want to start from the fundamentals and program all steps of the algorithm. I thought to use [this](https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/examples/training/train_textcat.py/) algorithm from spaCy, with small changes. This algorithm train the model to classify reviews into categories and then apply the model on new reviews. The only difference I see in my case is that the data I want to classify with the model is not at the same length as the training data (short sentences versus a few paragraphs). My questions are:

1. Does my plan make sense?
2. Any leads for a better algorithm for my problem?
3. Will it help to do additional training to the model, based on the text from the book I collected the tasks list from (this text is without classification of course. I mean to train the basic model, so it will know which words are similar to each other, or usually come together, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: are the short sentences different and/or specific enough, so you could clearly assign them to one of the patent-categories?

Comment: When I do it manually, most of the time the classification is easy. For example, "Disc and hoe" goes to "Soil working" class. Sometimes it is not clear, and one task can go to several classes. That is why I want it to be done mechanically, so I will have the probability of each task to belong to each of the classes.